# Calculus of Variations Open ball constraint

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

I'm stuck on this question,

Let $V$ be an open ball in $\mathbb R^3$ in $ { x,y,z \text{ st }x^2 +y^2 +z^2<1}$

I need to minimise the integral $$ \iiint_V (u_x^2+u_y^2+u_z^2) \, dx \, dy \, dz $$

when subject to constraints
$$ \iiint_V u \, dx \, dy \, dz = 4 \pi $$ 
and $$ u=1 \text{ on } \partial V$$

I've got down to this

$$ F= u_x^2+u_y^2+u_z^2 \text{ and } G=u$$
The Euler-Lagrange $$ {\partial\over \partial x}\left( {\partial (F- \lambda G)\over \partial u_x } \right)
 + {\partial\over \partial y}\left( {\partial (F- \lambda G)\over \partial u_y } \right)+{\partial\over \partial z}\left( {\partial (F- \lambda G)\over \partial u_z } \right)- {\partial\over \partial u}( F- \lambda G) =0 $$

I have worked out the above to be as follows and I know you simplify it to

$$ 2 u_{xx} + 2u_{yy}+ 2u_{zz} - \lambda =0$$
$$  \nabla^2 (u)= {\lambda \over 2} $$

Any suggestions on what to do next?

Comment: Yes. Check the sign of $\lambda$. (It does not really matter when it comes to finding the solution, but if you get back later you may get confused if the sign is wrong). Apart from that note that $\nabla^2 u$ is just the Laplacian. Do you know anything about solving $\Delta u = f$ ? It's rather hard to give you a hint here without having any idea what your background is.

Comment: I'm unsure how to apply the boundary conditions to work out the correct function

Comment: You still don't tell about your background. For solutions to $\Delta u = f$ on the unit ball there are explicit formulas (using a Greens function). Do you know this? These do take into account the boundary values. You may check formula (0.16) in this document: http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~sijue/greensfunction.pdf

Comment: I haven't learnt about this. But I switched to spherical polars and the question is now much easier

Comment: Yes. spherical polar coordinates is the alternative, then you get an ODE.